# Assertion failed for interface as gin.HandlerFunc

Tags: go, go-gin, type-assertion

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func Foo(ctx *gin.Context) {}

func main() {
    var v interface{}
    v = Foo
    _, ok := v.(func(*gin.Context))
    fmt.Println(ok) // true
    _, ok = v.(gin.HandlerFunc)
    fmt.Println(ok) // false
}
```

I have a function of interface type and want to convert it to gin.HandlerFunc, but what I can't understand is why the second assertion fails, I hope to get an answer, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Although a [`gin.HandlerFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#HandlerFunc) is [assignable](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability) to a `func(*gin.Context)` and vice versa, they are different types. A   `func(*gin.Context)` is not a `gin.HandlerFunc`.

Use this code to get a `gin.HandlerFunc` from an `interface{}`:

```
func handlerFunc(v interface{}) gin.HandlerFunc {
    switch v := v.(type) {
    case func(*gin.Context):
        return v
    case gin.HandlerFunc:
        return v
    default:
        panic("unexpected type")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I understand